# Put overflow divs on the next line using css

Tags: css

I have the following

```css
#1,
#2,
#3,
#4,
#5,
#6 {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

#main {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="1"><img scr="image1"></div>
  <div id="2"><img scr="image2"></div>
  <div id="3"><img scr="image3"></div>
  <div id="4"><img scr="image4"></div>
  <div id="5"><img scr="image5"></div>
  <div id="6"><img scr="image6"></div>
</div>
```

What it does for some reason is that the first 4 `div`s stay on the first row, but the last 2 `div` (5, 6) align in the center underneath `div`s 2 and 3.

How can I align the ones that don't fit to the left?

Comment: Are they aligned to the center, or stuck on `image1` because it's just a little taller than the rest?

Comment: they are aligned to the center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in my comment, on it's own, your code cannot create a center alignment, the following snippet uses placeholder images to show how it might look like 5 and 6 are center aligned though...

```css
.x1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

#main {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 210px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x51"></div>
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></div>
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></div>
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></div>
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></div>
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></div>
</div>
```

Either set the height of the divs, or start using flexbox. I'd recommend flex-box if you're not beholden to old browsers. The following snippet uses flex-box to resolve the issue, by using `display: flex` all child-elements are automagically made the same height as the tallest member of the `row`. By using `flex-wrap: wrap`, elements that no longer
fit horizontally, are moved to the next 'line'.

```css
.x1 {
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  clear: both;
  width: 210px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x51"></div>
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></div>
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></div>
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></div>
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></div>
  <div class="x1"><img scr="image6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"></div>
</div>
```